# (Cocos2D) Detect which CCScene is showing?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scene, cclayer

Is it possible to detect which CCScene is currently showing on the scene? I have 2 CCScenes in my game and I want a certain action to occur if one is showing.

Also quick related question, if I wanted to check if a CCMenu is ***not*** showing currently would I do something like

```
    if (!menu) { 
    //Menu is not showing currently
    }
```

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to Cocos2D so please forgive me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CCDirector to tell which scene is running.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
```

As for whether the menu is showing.  You would have to check with the parent of the menu.  If the parent where your CCLayer, then you could check by

```
// assume menu is set up to have tag kMenuTag
CCMenu * menu = [self getChildByTag:kMenuTag];
```

If the menu is child of some other node, you can get the parent through a similar method and get a reference to the menu.

If the `menu == nil`, it is not showing.

UPDATE

In cocos2d, you are discouraged from keeping references to all of your sprites, instead you should be giving each node a unique tag and use that to reference it.  To achieve your first goal, you can give your scene a tag in your 2 respective CCLayer classes.

You can set up your unique tags in an enum in a file called Tags.h, then import that into any classes that need access to your tags

Example Tags.h

```
enum {  
    kScene1Tag = 0,  
    kScene2Tag = 1,  
    kMenuTag = 2};
```

Then in your layer class

```
+(id) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    scene.tag = kScene1Tag;
    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorld *layer = [HelloWorld node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

Now when you grab the current scene you can check against the tags

```
int currentSceneTag = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene].tag;
if (currentSceneTag == kScene1Tag) {

} else if (currentSceneTag == kScene2Tag) {

}
```

The `tag` property is from `CCNode` which is the base class of `CCLayer`, `CCScene`, `CCSprite`, `CCMenu`...

Comment: Is there any way I can NSLog the current runningScene of my CCDirector, whenever I try to do an if statement detecting if one CCScene is open, it is always NO even if it should be YES.

Comment: Yes it did. Would another way be, to have a BOOL in a Singleton and just set it to YES or NO depending on the scene?

Comment: Yes, you could use a singleton to keep track of "state".  This would work for both keeping track of which scene is running and whether the menu is displayed.  Just keep in mind that you will have to update the  state every time you load a scene or hide/reveal the menu.

Comment: Of course! I am doing that now and it works well. Thanks for help again! Accepted and Up-Voted! :)

Comment: No problem.  If you aren't too far along, check out http://stackoverflow.com/users/201863/learncocos2d .  He answers a lot of cocos2d questions and developed his own extended and improved version of cocos2d.  I imagine it would be worth checking out.

Comment: Where are you assigning the tag to the menu layer? Is that automatic or just omitted from the example?

Answer (score 1):

This how to find out which scene is running

```
if ([CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene == yourScene1) {
    // your scene 1 is showing
} else {
    // your scene 2 is showing
}
```

and to find out if a node is child of the running scene

```
BOOL isShowing = NO;
CCNode *node = yourMenu;
while (node != nil) {
    if (node == [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene) {
        isShowing = YES;
        break;
    } else {
        node = node.parent;
    }
}
if (isShowing) {
    // your menu is in the display hierarchy 
}
```

Comment: Ok the first part is good but what does isShowing do in the second part, and why do I set the node to node.parent in the else part?